# ASP.Net .crt and .key domain certificate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I achieve this 'How to create an https server' Node.JS code in Asp.net (.Net 6)

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

I'm trying to get my domain certificate to work with my ASP.Net code but couldn't find a solution.
Is ASP.Net even made to handle Server and Browsers communication or mainly made for APIs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I attach an SSL certificate to my asp dot net website without switching to IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217702/how-do-i-attach-an-ssl-certificate-to-my-asp-dot-net-website-without-switching-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back when I attempted this in .NET Core 3.1 using `X509Certificate2` I could not get it to work.

What did work though was generating a `.pfx` certificate from the `.key` and `.crt` files in WSL (or Linux) using:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt
```

The resulting `server.pfx` certificate was accepted just fine by `X509Certificate2`.

Answer (score 1):

Got it by making a .pfx file (the answer) and referencing it this way: (.Net 6)

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

//Set Certificate
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    var crt = "cert.pfx";
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(crt);

    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80); // http
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions => // https
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection(); //MUST
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```